# Debugging a service with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In my current C++ project I am using visual studio 2019. The output binary sat target.exe  is used as a service and is created using `sc.exe create`  command.

When we run this service it crashes immediately.  So I need to debug this service. I was trying to use attach process but the service is getting crashed immediately. For a workaround I modify the code and add a 1 minute sleep in code. So now service is crashing after 1 minute and mean while I am able to attach the process. Now when service crashes, the vs output window only displaying

> The program '[17396] target.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

How can I debug this service and get the back-trace.
I have found one debug setting **Just My code** and already disabled it but has no effect.
Also enabled settings to break for all exceptions.

**Note** Running the binary directly gives the below error
[image: Error when debugging directly]

Comment: Search for "AeDebug" registry key. The functionality behind it allows you to start a debugger when a process with given name is started.

Comment: Sorry, scratch that, I remembered it wrong. It is actually "Image File Execution Options" to debug a service from start.

Comment: The way I do this is to have both a `ServiceMain` for when the app is being used as a service and `_tmain` for when I want to debug or run the app from the command line.

Comment: @user20716902 Thanks for suggestion. The code is already using _tmain and was calling ServiceBase::Run(). After trying some changes I am able to run it as stand alone program.

Comment: @RakeshMehta Hi Rakesh, if you found a solution, you can post the detailed steps as an answer, this will help others who meet the similar issue. :)